# Bound mismatch: The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type

Tags: java

I have a class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private TreeNode<E> root;
    //other methods like insert, etc
}

public class TreeNode<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<V>{
    //left and right instances of TreeNode and data holder V instance. 
    //insert method, etc
    @Override
    public int compareTo(V o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So far so good.

When I write this code with in class `BinarySearchTree`,:

```
public void levelOrderTraversalQueue() {
    Queue<TreeNode<E>> q = new Queue(); //<--Bound mismatch: The type BinarySearchTree<E>.TreeNode<E> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type Queue<E>
}
```

Why is that? My Queue class is implemented like this:

```
public class Queue<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private LinkedList<E> list;
    //other operations
}
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: You never said `TreeNode` is `Comparable`. You just said `V` is `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
public class TreeNode<...> implements Comparable<V>{
```

means that a `TreeNode` can be compared to a `V` - the thing it is storing.

That's not what you mean. To be able to put a tree node into your `Queue`, a tree node needs the ability to be compared with *another tree node*. Recall:

```
Queue<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

Whatever `E` is, it must implement `Comparable<E>`. Here, `E` is `TreeNode<V>`.

Therefore you should write:

```
public class TreeNode<...> implements Comparable<TreeNode<V>> {
```